# Google maps key with deleted google play account

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I have created google map api key from a goole account which is not enabled now its deleted.but my google maps are still working in my ios application.my concern is do i need to create key from different account ,   will deleted google account affects my existing key?

Comment: try to delete the app and clear cash then reinstalled, in this case does the map key still working?

Comment: yes, i already did this,deleted and reinstalled application and its still working

Comment: i'm sure that there is something wrong sometimes google apps save some cash but in case u delete the app from google console and then deleted the app from local device it should not work again

Comment: try to create new acount, new app and use the new key